Как диагностировать ПК?
Что-то странное у меня происходит с ПК. Началось все с того, что после перестановки видеокарты, иногда перестают проходит тесты VGA при запуске биоса. При этом решение странное: обесточил, вынул, вставил, запустил. Бывает срабатывает с первого раза, бывает с 10-го.
На днях переезжал, привез комп, включил. Непроходят тесты DRAM. 4 планки. Вынул все. Вставил первую - незапускается. Вставил вторую - ок. Вставил остальные - ок. Возвращаю первую - незапускается. Окей, работал пару дней на трех планках. Сегодня отвез планку в ремонт. Вставили, запустили - ок. Возвращаюсь домой, возвращаю планку на место, запускаю - ок. Что за магия!?
Такая же история и с видеокартой. Теперь к ней присоединилась ОЗУ.
А с видюхой началась еще проблема, когда играю в игру, то часто обороты кулеров видеокарты прыгают до 4-х тысяч оборотов в минуту! Секунд на 5. Это 130% от максимальной скорости, которую я могу выставить в настройках афтербернера. Скачал его, в надежде, что он предотвратит скачки оборотов кулеров. Смотрел графики, ничего кроме оборотов кулера не ведет себя странно. При этом есть еще график процента скорости. Типо можно выставить скорость кулеров на 80%. Так вот при прыжке оборотов, процент скорости неменяется. как я выставил так и остается.

Материнка: AURUS Z390 PRO WIFI
Процессор: i9-9900KF
RAM: Patriot Viper RGB PVR416G360C7K x4
VGA:  RTX 2080 SUPER
Power: Corsair HX850g

Я сбрасывал биос, переставлял видюху в другой слот PCI. Ничего не меняется. Прошу помощи в диагностике: "что смортеть", "что проверить"?

Конфигурация системы:
️~$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-124-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI-CF v: x.x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: F11
    date: 10/15/2019
Battery:
  Device-1: hid-dc:2c:26:29:dd:3d-battery model: Keychron K3 charge: N/A
    status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: Intel Core i9-9900KF bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Coffee Lake rev: C cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 2 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 800 min/max: 800/5000 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800
    4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800 13: 800
    14: 800 15: 800 16: 800 bogomips: 115200
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER] vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: nvidia v: 550.120 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 2560x1440~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 550.120 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU104 HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Device-3: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series]
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 04:00.0
  Device-4: BKD-11 Pro Audio Device type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-13.4:10
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-124-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I219-V vendor: Gigabyte driver: e1000e v: kernel
    port: N/A bus-ID: 00:1f.6
  IF: eno2 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-820b09f5358e state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: br-a3c90f726048 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: br-b47b70aeaaf0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-4: br-c573d31674c8 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-5: br-cc2aa0ea05bd state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-6: br-cf3e7f32bc1c state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-7: br-fe5185f48bee state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-8: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-9: outline-tun0 state: down mac: N/A
  IF-ID-10: veth550ed20 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-11: veth66a60fe state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-12: veth880ee45 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-13: veth8f51485 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-14: veth9b8d302 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-15: vethcadd9fd state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-16: vethe8e14a4 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP) type: USB
    driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-14:11
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0
    bus-ID: 00:17.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.38 TiB used: 819.39 GiB (57.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKNW512G8 size: 476.94 GiB
    temp: 40.9 C
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
    size: 931.51 GiB temp: 42.9 C
  ID-3: /dev/sda type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Cruzer Fit size: 7.45 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 465.29 GiB used: 409.38 GiB (88.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
    mapped: vgmint-root
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.89 GiB used: 569.8 MiB (29.5%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 980 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/dm-2 mapped: vgmint-swap_1
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C pch: 56.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia
    temp: 53 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0%
Info:
  Processes: 422 Uptime: 33m Memory: 31.27 GiB used: 3.3 GiB (10.5%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 2487 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
 ️~$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 64 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 8502
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 3600 C17 Series     
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 8502
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 3600 C17 Series     
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 8502
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 3600 C17 Series     
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 8502
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 3600 C17 Series     
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V


Самый простой вариант - окислившиеся контакты на разъемых соединениях что у памяти, что у карты. Я каждый раз, когда что-то собираю, память и PCI-E вставляю/вытаскиваю по несколько раз и тереблю в разъемах для профилактики подобных проблем. Можно ластиком почистить, если проблема запущенная. Только со статикой осторожнее, особенно в холодное время года, желательно сначала что-нибудь металлическое и заземленное потрогать.

Ну ещё как вариант мать может глючить. И БП на самом деле не тянуть. Но это всё менее вероятно уже.

нагрузку на бп тестану, спасибо. а материнку попробую помыть. выну батарейку и подкран суну. посмотрим что получится.

Эээ, под какой кран?! С водой?! )))  Только продувать сжатым воздухом. Ну и чем-то специальным промывать, но чем именно я не знаю.

а почему водой нельзя? питания небудет. вода слишком агресивная среда? может тогда дисцилированную воду? мне неверится что сжатый воздух уберет окисления) или залипаня, какие бывают от капель пива или сладкого чая)

Ну я бы понял спиртом каким... Вода забьётся куда-нибудь, окислит контакты, ржавчина, все дела.

никакой воды, а по хорошему и никаких спирто-содержащих, бензо-подобных жиж. если вода на раз два по-окисляет всё голое, то бензы\спирты оголят всё что было хоть как то влаго-защищенным(сожгут изоляцию дорожек)... если с химией туго, берешь листодувку либо обычный фен для волос, и сдуваешь ими пыль\грязь(дыханием не стоит - выдыхаешь кучу влаги) что останется - оттираешь сухой ваткой\салфеткой. контакты ластиком можно протереть(после очистки пальцами контакты не трогай, отпечатки остаются в виде пятен жира, медь они, жиры эти - тоже окисляют наскок помню).

на счет запуска через раз - как раз контакты и загажены скорее всего(может на плашках\карте, а может и в слотах, потому слоты тоже стоит продуть хорошенько). обороты кулеров видеокарты прыгают до 4-х тысяч оборотов! Это 130% от максимальной скорости, которую я могу выставить вероятно незаметный бёрнеру перегрев(не все термометры мониторишь). если давно не обслуживал или наоборот - как раз перед появлением обслужил, стоит поправить охлад. мб где термопрокладка до памяти теперь недостаёт. если не уверен в скилах - тащить в сервис. если такое после сервиса - в другой сервис...
